# Creation of Virtual environment with python 3.9 version is executed successfully but python version 2.7 or python version 2.2 shows error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtual-environment

When creating a virtual environment using the 'virtualenv' module, using python 3.11 as deafult/ in the Path, in WINDOWS 10 , I encounter the following weird error. Creation of a virtualenvironment with python 3.9 which is installed in  "E:\python33\python.exe" is successful, but creation of virtual environment with python python 2.2 or 2.7 which is also installed in "E:\python27\python.exe" fails. Following are the errors shown in command prompt.

```
C:\Users\abc\Desktop>virtualenv -p E:\python27\python.exe tl343f
RuntimeError: failed to query E:\python27\python.exe with code 1 err: '  File "C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\virtualenv\\discovery\\py_info.py", line 24\n    return list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(["", *os.environ.get("PATHEXT", "").lower().split(os.pathsep)]))\n                                          ^\nSyntaxError: invalid syntax\n'

C:\Users\abc\Desktop>virtualenv -p E:\python33\python.exe kljkj33
created virtual environment CPython3.9.12.final.0-64 in 738ms
  creator CPython3Windows(dest=C:\Users\abc\Desktop\kljkj33, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\pypa\virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==23.2.1, setuptools==68.2.0, wheel==0.41.2
  activators BashActivator,BatchActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

C:\Users\abc\Desktop>
```

I am expecting the code to execute similar to how it executes when I want to create a virtual environment with python3.9 version. But it fails when creating a virtual environment with python2.7 or python2.2 version

Comment: Python 2.2 is paleolithic, surely you can't have a version older than 2.4 (or even 2.6) unless you are a time traveler.

Answer (score 1):

According to [[Python]: Sunsetting Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2) (**emphasis** is mine):

> We have decided that **January 1, 2020, was the day that we sunset Python 2**.

It's no longer supported for more than **3.5 years**. I'm not even going to discuss *Python 2.2* (as it has been probably dead for more than 10 years).

[[PyPI]: virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv) only supports ***Python >= v3.7***. Syntax in *VirtualEnv* files is no longer compatible with *Python 2*, that's why you get the error.

So, you should move away from *Python 2.7* to a more actual (and decent) version (*v3.8* is oldest version currently supported (in *security* mode)).

As a workaround, you could install (and use) [[PyPI]: virtualenv 20.15.1](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/20.15.1), which is the **newest *VirtualEnv* version still supporting *Python 2***.

Answer (score 0):

Install `virtualenv` with Python 2.7:

```
E:\python27\python.exe -m pip install -U "pip<21.0" "setuptools<45" wheel
E:\python27\python.exe -m pip install -U virtualenv
```

and use it:

```
E:\python27\python.exe -m virtualenv venv
```

PS. Python 2.2 and Python 3 less than 3.4 are too old an unusable. But there is nothing wrong with 2.7 and 3.4+.